# Highlight several table cells with headers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to highlight table cells when mouse drug on that cell. I really want to do
1. when mouse drug on the table cell that are highlighted by a border.
2. Which cells are highlighted the headers of that cell are also highlighted.
How can I do this?
Thank you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(window).load(function() {
     $(function () {
         $("#Mytable td")
             .mousedown(rangeMouseDown)
             .mouseup(rangeMouseUp)
             .mousemove(rangeMouseMove);
     });

     var dragStart = 0;
     var dragEnd = 0;
     var isDragging = false;

     function rangeMouseDown(e) {
         if (isRightClick(e)) {
             return false;
         } else {
             var allCells = $("#Mytable td");
             dragStart = allCells.index($(this));
             isDragging = true;

             if (typeof e.preventDefault != 'undefined') { e.preventDefault(); }
             document.documentElement.onselectstart = function () { return false; };
         }
     }

     function rangeMouseUp(e) {
         if (isRightClick(e)) {
             return false;
         } else {
             var allCells = $("#Mytable td");
             dragEnd = allCells.index($(this));

             isDragging = false;
             if (dragEnd != 0) {
                 selectRange();
             }

             document.documentElement.onselectstart = function () { return true; };
         }
     }

     function rangeMouseMove(e) {
         if (isDragging) {
             var allCells = $("#Mytable td");
             dragEnd = allCells.index($(this));
             selectRange();
         }
     }

     function selectRange() {
         $("#Mytable td").removeClass('selected');
         if (dragEnd + 1 < dragStart) { // reverse select
             $("#Mytable td").slice(dragEnd, dragStart + 1).addClass('highlighte');
         } else {
             $("#Mytable td").slice(dragStart, dragEnd + 1).addClass('highlighte');
         }
     }

     function isRightClick(e) {
         if (e.which) {
             return (e.which == 3);
         } else if (e.button) {
             return (e.button == 2);
         }
         return false;
     }
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: [You shouldn't be drugging innocent mice.](http://www.animalsaustralia.org/take_action/stop-animal-tests/) More seriously, could you perhaps edit your question to show your existing html (or a reasonable sample of it) and any JavaScript that you've already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you already have requirement #1 working fine in your code, to highlight the headers you could add this to your `selectRange()` function to get the index of the selected cells and add the class to the corresponding headers:

```
function selectRange() {
    $("#Mytable td").removeClass('selected');
    if (dragEnd + 1 < dragStart) { // reverse select
       var tds = $("#Mytable td").slice(dragEnd, dragStart + 1).addClass('highlighted');
    } else {
       var tds = $("#Mytable td").slice(dragStart, dragEnd + 1).addClass('highlighted');
    }
    tds.each(function(){
        $('#Mytable th').eq($(this).index()).addClass('highlighted');
    });    
 }
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awpDA/2/)**

Comment: Here we can see that each selected cell has four sided border. If I need total selection has one four sided border means if I select 5 cells from row 2 and row 3 then get only one four side border around row 2 and row 3 with 5 cells . Then which can I do?